# javascript value to php variable in zend framework 2

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, zend-framework

in my view file:

```
$.post("<?php echo $this->url('checkcourse'); ?>", {},
    function(data) {
        if (data){
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
                // here i am trying to assign js value to PHP variable
                <?php 
                    $course = "<script language=javascript>document.write('data[i].code');</script>";
                ?> 
                $('<option value="'+data[i].code+'"<?php echo ($course == $projectDetail['cname'])?"selected":"" ?> >'+data[i].domain+'</option>').appendTo('#code');
            }
         }else{
             alert('no data');
         }     
    }, "json");
```

data[i].code is the original js value accessing from database, now i want to make a selected attribute for the value which is already in database

Comment: It is not possible to assign javascript value to php. what you want to do with $course after ajax request complete?

Comment: yea what is the purpose of $course?

Comment: $('<option value="'+data[i].code+'"<?php echo ($course == $projectDetail['cname'])?"selected":"" ?> >'+data[i].domain+'</option>').appendTo('#code');  // comparing $course with $projectDetails['cname'], if both are same then i need a selected attribute in option tag